# Need help with html tags in iphone

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode

I have made a string like this one..

```
NSString *loadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body bgcolor=\"red\"><font color=\"white\">%@</font></body></html>", string];
```

and now I m loading this string in a UIWEbView like

```
[webView loadHTMLString:loadString baseURL:nil];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

now i should get the background color as red but m not getting any colour its all white. can anyone identify what mistake i m making. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

change the opaque value to what is needed
backgroundColor can be transparent clearColor or any color you like (for example:redColor)

```
myWebView.opaque = NO;
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:
@"<html><body style='background-color: transparent'>
       Content</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: you should except answers before asking for more help

Comment: NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                "<head> \n"
                                "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                                "</style> \n"
                                "</head> \n"
                                "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], content];

Comment: one sec. I m able to change font size and family but still cant change color. I want to change the color of the font.. any guide line..?